# Android/Kotlin: Error: "Expecting a top level declaration > Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug"

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, companion-object

I try to write a class to manage a SQLite DB, but I have the error message "Expecting a top level declaration > Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug".

```
   package com.xexxxwxxxxs.GMP

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.ContentValues

    class DBHandler(context: Context, name: String?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION)
    {
        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase)
        {

        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int)
        {

        }

        companion object
        {
            private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
            private val DATABASE_NAME = "GMP.db"
        }
    }﻿
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I just delete the last curly brace and write it again. It's working :)

Comment: You just killed me :D It works. Incredible... It seems that there is a invisble character at the end.

Comment: In my case there was an extra closing braces

Comment: Just when I though that there is no place for black magic in the coding. hehe. Thanks.

Comment: I found the same error because I used a `-` dash in fun name...

Answer (score 6):

The same happened to me, you just need to remove an auto-generated extra curly bracket at the end, then it works.

Comment: I had a slightly fancier version: I had to delete the last three brackets and put them back in again.

Answer (score 1):

I had recently changed my package name (e.g., com.example.myappname) and found that the `MainActivity.kt` package name on Line 1 was not updated to the new name -- which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error can show up if you have defined any object outside of class declaration

example  :
`class someActivity extands something{ } private someMethod(){}`

to solve this   just move  it inside

`class someActivity extands something{

private someMethod(){}
}`

Answer (score -1):

If, like me, you are working in `code` (VSCode), you should remove the call to `main()` at the end of the file. For example

```kotlin
fun main(){
println("This will fail")
}
main()
```

For the above, we shall get the following error:

> your_file.kt:50:6: error: expecting a top level declaration
> main()

Removing the call to `main()` fixes the issue.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why should we put function invoked(i.e `println()`) into `main` ?

Comment: Only in vscode. It automatically runs it.